# Swap using Xor producing erronous result

Tags: c

This is a weird error that I am getting for a simple selection sort.

Use the following inputs `89,52,10,1,56,63,24,36,12,5`

If you were to debug it you would notice that during the 3rd iteration the line 
`a[i]=a[i] ^ a[min];` sets both operand to zero.

Any Idea why this is happening ?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[10]={'\0'};
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    int min=0;

    printf("Enter 10 Elements\n");

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        min=i;

        for(j=i+1;j<10;j++)
        {
            if(a[j]<a[min])
            {
                min=j;
            }
        }


        a[i]=a[i] ^ a[min];
        a[min]= a[min] ^ a[i];
        a[i]= a[i] ^ a[min];
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("\n %d",a[i]);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XOR is a lousy way to swap variables.  Just declare a temporary and use assignments.

The XOR trick:

```
x = x ^ y;
y = y ^ x;
x = x ^ y;
```

fails if `x` and `y` are the same location in memory; it will then set the value to 0.

I haven't analyzed your code in detail, but I'll bet that this:

```
a[i]=a[i] ^ a[min];
a[min]= a[min] ^ a[i];
a[i]= a[i] ^ a[min];
```

is failing when `i == min`.

...

Confirmed, I tried running the program with an added `printf` statement, and with the specified input it does the swap with `i == min` at least once.

Comment: you are right it fails when i==min, Is there any particular reason why both operands are being set to zero. ?? Shouldn't the assignment operator just assign the new value to a[i] and not affect the value of a[min]...

Comment: No.  The problem is that, if `x` and `y` are the same object, `x = x ^ y` modifies both `x` and `y`.  Any number xor'ed with itself is zero. The way to swap two variables is `tmp = x; x = y; y = tmp;` (You might also adjust your algorithm so it doesn't unnecessarily try to swap an element with itself; it's not necessarily an error, but it's wasteful.)

Comment: oh ok.. I'vw always used the Temp variable swapping method before, but heard that this was a more efficient way to swap variables since it has no memory overhead of an additional variable..so just wrote a program to test it out..  but thanks anyway.. ill stick to the tried and tested here with the temp variable..  :)

Comment: Using xor to swap two variables is very clever, in the *bad* sense of the word "clever".

Comment: Additional efficiency is worthless if it makes your program incorrect.  Also, on any CPU that implements register renaming (not all do, but probably you're using one if you care about performance rather than code density or power efficiency), the XOR trick is going to be _slower_.

Answer (score 0):

When two pointers designate the same memory location, the program will fail. And this is called memory aliasing.